# If $f(17) = 17$, calculate $A(x) = \int_{1}^{x} f(t)dt$ for $x>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. For $x>0$, $y>0$ and any $x'$ in $(0, \infty)$ we have that

$$\int_{x}^{xy} f(u) \ du = \int_{x'}^{x'y} f(u) \ du.$$

If $f(17) = 17$, calculate $A(x) = \int_{1}^{x} f(t)dt$ for $x>0$.

I got this:

$$\begin{align}
A(xy) &= \int_{1}^{xy} f(t)dt \\
&=\int_{1}^{x} f(t)dt + \int_{x}^{xy} f(t)dt \\
&= \int_{1}^{x} f(t)dt + \int_{1}^{y} f(t)dt \\
&= A(x) + A(y)
\end{align}$$

and $$\frac{dA(xy)}{dy} = \frac{dA(xy)}{dy} y = A'(x).$$

With this we have that $A'
(17y)= \frac{f(17)}{y}$.

Here I got stuck. What else I can do?

Comment: Make the substitution $u = 17y$ and integrate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you wanted to write $A(x) := \int_{1}^{x} f(t)dt$ instead of $A(x) = \int_{2}^{x} f(t)dt$. Then, as you had seen, we get the equation $A(xy)=A(x)+A(y)$, and so
$$
\begin{align*}
A(xy)=A(x)+A(y)&\implies \partial_y A(xy)=A'(xy)x=A'(y)\\
&\implies f(xy)x=f(y)\\
&\implies f(17x)=\frac{17}x\\
&\implies f(s)=\frac{(17)^2}s,\quad s:=17x\\
&\implies \int_1^x f(s)\,\mathrm d s=(17)^2\int_1^x\frac1s\,\mathrm d s\\
&\implies A(x)=(17)^2\ln(x)
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 3):

We can differentiate the original identity with respect to $y$ to obtain:
$$xf(xy) = \frac{d}{dy}\int_{x}^{xy}f(t)\,dt = \frac{d}{dy}\int_{x'}^{x'y}f(t)\,dt = x'f(x'y)$$
for all $x,x',y > 0$. Plugging in $x' = 17$ and $y = 1$ gives
$$xf(x) = 17f(17) = 17^2 = 289$$
or $$f(x) = \frac{289}{x}$$
for all $x > 0$.

Now for all $x > 0$ we have

$$A(x) = \int_1^x f(t)\,dt = \int_1^x\frac{289}{t}\, = 289\ln x$$